# Generating binary segmentation file for lane detection in Python/Tensorflow (Tusimple Lanenet Dataset)

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, image-processing, computer-vision

I was using the code from https://github.com/MaybeShewill-CV/lanenet-lane-detection which using Deep Learning to detect road lane lines.

I successfully tested the model. Now I want to retrain the model on my own data.

The training data consisted of three parts: the original image, the binary segmentation file and the instance segmentation file. Please refer to both `gt_image_binary` and `gt_image_instance` folders inside the `/data/training_data_example` folder from the repo.

The binary segmentation use 255 to represent the lane field and 0 for the rest. The instance use different pixel value to represent different lane field and 0 for the rest.

My question is how do I generate these two labels (binary and instance segmentation files)?

The author said that you just need to follow the guidelines in the readme file for the Tusimple Lanenet Dataset found here: https://github.com/TuSimple/tusimple-benchmark/blob/master/doc/lane_detection/readme.md

And from this, it states that you can generate these files using this format in json file:

```
{
      'raw_file': str. 20th frame file path in a clip.
      'lanes': list. A list of lanes. For each list of one lane, the elements are width values on image.
      'h_samples': list. A list of height values corresponding to the 'lanes', which means len(h_samples) == len(lanes[i])
    }
```

Where each json line in 'label_data_(date).json' is the label data for the frame.

e.g.

```
{
  "lanes": [
        [-2, -2, -2, -2, 632, 625, 617, 609, 601, 594, 586, 578, 570, 563, 555, 547, 539, 532, 524, 516, 508, 501, 493, 485, 477, 469, 462, 454, 446, 438, 431, 423, 415, 407, 400, 392, 384, 376, 369, 361, 353, 345, 338, 330, 322, 314, 307, 299],
        [-2, -2, -2, -2, 719, 734, 748, 762, 777, 791, 805, 820, 834, 848, 863, 877, 891, 906, 920, 934, 949, 963, 978, 992, 1006, 1021, 1035, 1049, 1064, 1078, 1092, 1107, 1121, 1135, 1150, 1164, 1178, 1193, 1207, 1221, 1236, 1250, 1265, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2],
        [-2, -2, -2, -2, -2, 532, 503, 474, 445, 416, 387, 358, 329, 300, 271, 241, 212, 183, 154, 125, 96, 67, 38, 9, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2],
        [-2, -2, -2, 781, 822, 862, 903, 944, 984, 1025, 1066, 1107, 1147, 1188, 1229, 1269, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2]
       ],
  "h_samples": [240, 250, 260, 270, 280, 290, 300, 310, 320, 330, 340, 350, 360, 370, 380, 390, 400, 410, 420, 430, 440, 450, 460, 470, 480, 490, 500, 510, 520, 530, 540, 550, 560, 570, 580, 590, 600, 610, 620, 630, 640, 650, 660, 670, 680, 690, 700, 710],
  "raw_file": "path_to_clip"
}
```

Then you will just overlay the points on the original image (using cv2.polylines?).

How do I do this?

I tried to create both binary and instance segmentation files by just drawing a line (in paint, yes) on a black background. Then I got a shape error, so I converted them to grayscale. I also checked the original files which are also in grayscale so I followed this image format.

But again, I got error doing this.

What is the best way to generate the binary and instance segmentation files?

Answer (score 0):

I will just drop an answer here (Don't know if it's good to answer an old question).

```
label = '0601'
labe_filename = 'label_data_%s.json' % label
clips = [json.loads(line) for line in open(labe_filename).readlines()]

for clip in clips:
    lanes = clip['lanes']
    filepath = clip['raw_file']
    ysamples = clip['h_samples']

    lanes = [[(x, y) for (x, y) in zip(lane, ysamples) if x >= 0] for lane in lanes]

    raw_image = cv2.imread(filepath)
    label_image = np.zeros(raw_image.shape[:2], dtype=np.uint8)

    for lane in lanes:
        cv2.polylines(label_image, np.int32([lane]), isClosed=False, color=(255,255,255), thickness=5)

    cv2.imshow("win1", raw_image)
    cv2.imshow("win2", label_image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    break
```

Tusimple dataset uses something like scanline to form markings for lanes ([this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TuSimple/tusimple-benchmark/master/doc/lane_detection/assets/examples/lane_example.jpg)). `h_samples` are the y coordinates of scanlines. So you need to combine `h_samples` and `lanes` (which are the x coordinates) to form a lane marking. And if there is no existing lane marking, `x` coordinate will be 0. That's what this line does:

```
lanes = [[(x, y) for (x, y) in zip(lane, ysamples) if x >= 0] for lane in lanes]
```

For instance segmentation, use different color for each lane. You may refer to their data provider codes to address the shape errors.